# curl php error 1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl

I have a web page that calls another web page using php and curl running on IIS.

and all of a sudden i recieve this

error 1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

The curl code I have is

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

I have searched high and low and have come to the conclusion my openssl and php is way out of date

php 5.3.27 and SSL Version  OpenSSL/0.9.8y

I Imagine the target company's APIs i hit no longer support the lower version of this SSL

I was after advice on how to update php_openssl.dll to fix this. I did download a new version of php (7.2) and copy the php_openssl.dll from there to the current php installation ext directory, and stop and restart IIS. I am pretty sure this is not the right way to fix, but I am not that up to date with updating dlls.

when i rerun phpinfo.php this has no affect.

thanks

Comment: excellent catch!! :)